# Validar todos os campos required dataannotations nas tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou utilizando tabs do `bootstrap` e utilizo o `dataannotations` para incluir o `required`. Porém ele não valida todos os campos, eu preciso que ele valide o required, e caso não esteja validado, ele selecione esta `tab`.
Fiz para tentar localizar os campos, porém ele só localiza os da tab selecionada.

Tentei este código abaixo, porém também não funcionou:

```
    $('#FornecedorNovo').on('submit', function () {
    $(this).find('input[aria-required=true]').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert('O campo ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' é obrigatório!');
            return false;
        }
    });
});

<form asp-action="Novo" id="FornecedorNovo">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:60px">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"> Adicionar Fornecedor</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row with-nav-tabs" style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; padding-top:00px;">
                <input id="hdnfldVariable" type="hidden" value="1" />
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
                        <li class="active"><a id="lnkfragment1" href="#fragment-1" data-toggle="tab"><span>Dados Cadastrais</span></a></li>
                        <li><a id="lnkfragment2" href="#fragment-2" data-toggle="tab"><span>Adicionais</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="fragment-1" style="border-style: none; height:150px;" class="tab-pane active">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Codigo" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Codigo" class="form-control labelcss" readonly placeholder="Insira o nome do fornecedor.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Codigo" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" class="form-control" readonly>
                            <label asp-for="Nome" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input asp-for="Nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o nome do fornecedor.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="NomeFantasia" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input asp-for="NomeFantasia" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o nome do fornecedor.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="NomeFantasia" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <label asp-for="Contato" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input asp-for="Contato" class="form-control" placeholder="Contato.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Contato" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail comercial.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Tel1" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Tel1" class="form-control" placeholder="(00) 0000-0000" data-mask="(00) 0000-0000">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Tel1" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <label asp-for="Tel2" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Tel2" class="form-control" placeholder="(00) 0000-0000" data-mask="(00) 0000-0000">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Tel2" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <label asp-for="Tel3" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Tel3" class="form-control" placeholder="(00) 0000-0000" data-mask="(00) 0000-0000">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Tel3" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Cel1" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Cel1" class="form-control" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" data-mask="(00) 00000-0000">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Cel1" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <label asp-for="Cel2" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Cel2" class="form-control" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" data-mask="(00) 00000-0000">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Cel2" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>

                            <label asp-for="Cel3" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Cel3" class="form-control" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" data-mask="(00) 00000-0000">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Cel3" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="fragment-2" style="border-style: none; height:150px;" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Rua" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input asp-for="Rua" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira a rua do fornecedor.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Rua" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>

                            <label asp-for="Numero" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Numero" class="form-control" placeholder="Nº.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Numero" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Bairro" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input asp-for="Bairro" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o bairro do fornecedor.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Bairro" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <label asp-for="Complemento" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input asp-for="Complemento" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o complemento do endereço.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Complemento" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Cidade" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input asp-for="Cidade" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira a cidade.">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Cidade" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <label asp-for="Cep" class="col-md-1 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input asp-for="Cep" class="form-control" placeholder="00000-000" data-mask="00000-000">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Cep" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <label asp-for="Estado" class="col-md-1 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <select asp-for="Estado" class="form-control">
                                    <option disabled selected>Selecione</option>
                                    <option value="AC">AC</option>
                                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                                    <option value="AM">AM</option>
                                    <option value="AP">AP</option>
                                    <option value="BA">BA</option>
                                    <option value="CE">CE</option>
                                    <option value="DF">DF</option>
                                    <option value="ES">ES</option>
                                    <option value="GO">GO</option>
                                    <option value="MA">MA</option>
                                    <option value="MG">MG</option>
                                    <option value="MS">MS</option>
                                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                                    <option value="PA">PA</option>
                                    <option value="PB">PB</option>
                                    <option value="PE">PE</option>
                                    <option value="PI">PI</option>
                                    <option value="PR">PR</option>
                                    <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
                                    <option value="RN">RN</option>
                                    <option value="RS">RS</option>
                                    <option value="RO">RO</option>
                                    <option value="RR">RR</option>
                                    <option value="SC">SC</option>
                                    <option value="SE">SE</option>
                                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                                    <option value="TO">TO</option>
                                </select>
                                @*<input asp-for="Estado" class="form-control">*@
                                <span asp-validation-for="Estado" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="TipoPessoa" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <select asp-for="TipoPessoa" class="form-control" onchange="VerificaMascara();">
                                    <option value="Juridica">Jurídica</option>
                                    <option value="Fisica">Física</option>
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="TipoPessoa" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input asp-for="Documento" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Documento" id="message" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="InscricaoEstadual" id="inscricao" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input asp-for="InscricaoEstadual" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
                                <span asp-validation-for="InscricaoEstadual" id="messageI" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <input asp-for="InscricaoIsento" type="checkbox" />
                            <label asp-for="InscricaoIsento" id="isento" class="control-label"></label>
                            <span asp-validation-for="InscricaoIsento" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="CategoriaFornecedorID" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <select asp-for="CategoriaFornecedorID" asp-items="@Model.CategoriaFornecedorList" id="cbcategoria" class="form-control">
                                    <option disabled selected>Selecione</option>
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="CategoriaFornecedorID" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <th style="text-align:right"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCategoria" title="Adicionar Nova Categoria" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></a></th>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Observacao" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <textarea asp-for="Observacao" class="form-control" placeholder="Observações do fornecedor."></textarea>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Observacao" class="text-danger"></span>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <input type="submit" name="name" id="btnConcluir" class="btn btn-info" value="Concluir" />&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Então só confirmando, você teria outras tabs porém dentro do evento submit ? tem como postar seu html ? ou parte dele ?

Comment: Quem seria FornecedorNovo no seu html ?

Comment: @MateusVeloso FornedorNovo é o id do meu `html`, o evento submit é do form.

Comment: Preciso do seu html, ficaria mais simples de te ajudar, e não teria chance de erro

Comment: Existe um botão editar abaixo de sua pergunta, adicione o trecho do seu html que irei te ajudar!

Comment: @MateusVeloso inseri o HTML completo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo com uma validação personalizada utilizando javascript e jQuery, posso fazer o exemplo com 100% javascript caso precise!

Vamos entender o exemplo.

> Primeiro passo é capturar o evento submit do form (FornecedorNovo)
>
> Próximo passo é verificar se existe um valor valido em todos os inputs que tem a tag data-required com o valor true.
>
> Caso exista algum valor null, undefined ou vazio iremos acrescentar uma borda vermelha ( apenas para teste e ver quem está errado ) , enviar um alert e impedir o submit do form.

**Com esse exemplo talvez você consiga modificar seu código e assim fazer suas validações personalizadas!**

**Referencias:**

[jQuery ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```js
$('#FornecedorNovo').on('submit', function (e) {
  $.each($('input[data-required="true"]'),function(){
    if(!this.value || this.value == ''){
      $(this).css('border','red 1px solid');
      alert('Preencha os campos corretamente!');
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form id="FornecedorNovo">
    <input type="text" id="nome" value="" data-required="true">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Concluir</button>
  </form>
  <input type="text" id="nomeFora" value="" data-required="true">
```

Comment: Ele continua validando somente o da tab selecionada, ignorando a outra.

Comment: No seu código eu não vi fechando a tag form, ele está completo ? existem outros forms ?

Comment: Outro ponto é , alterou o script para chegar nos "campos obrigatorios" ?

Comment: Ele fecha sim, apaguei sem querer quando fui incluir o código, e ele só funciona assim na tab selecionada, se eu clicar duas vezes no button submit, eu troquei para aria-required pois utilizo o dataannotations.

Comment: Okay, altere o código por favor, como ficou pós atualização.

Comment: Eu não mudei o HTML, eu só alterei o código que você me passou na sua resposta. `$('#FornecedorNovo').on('submit', function (e) {
        $.each($('input[aria-required="true"]'), function () {
            if (!this.value || this.value == '') {
                $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                alert('Preencha os campos corretamente!');
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });`

Comment: Exatamente, por isso nao funcionou , perceba que no código javascript estamos buscando por todos os inputs que tem data-required como atributo, faça a alteração no html , retire o aria-required, pois no código que passei é data-required,

Comment: Voce vai ter agora inputs assim <input type="text" data-required="true"> entendeu ? e no código javascript vai achar eles pelo atributo "data-required"

Comment: Funcionou, porém ele não muda de aba.

Comment: Como assim, você quer que mude a aba para qual o input está vazio ?

Comment: Sim, é possível ?

Comment: Tudo é possivel jovem haha, me de um segundo, vou fazer um exemplo com abas.

Comment: Melhor vou te explicar por aqui como fazer

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84955/discussion-between-mateus-veloso-and-marianac-costa).

Answer (score 0):

O problema e na sua expressao `$(this)` pq ela vai usar apenas a tab selecionada, vc deveria usar algo como `$('.tab-content')` para procurar por todos os seus inputs

```
$('#FornecedorNovo').on('submit', function () {
    $('.tab-content').find('input[aria-required=true]').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert('O campo ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' é obrigatório!');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Inclui o HTML do form. Não entendi muito bem a sua resposta.

Comment: alterei algora @marianac_costa

Comment: Não funcionou, ele continua validando somente da tab selecionada.